# Page Replacement Algorithm fifo

Tags: linux

I have to use the First-In-First-Out (FIFO) Page Replacement Algorithm on the next sequence :1,3,4,1,2,1,4,3,4,2,1 for 4 blocks. The problem is on adding the second 1. Can I add it twice?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need to expand quite significantly on your question before it becomes answerable. See [ask] for more detail.

Comment: IMO no, since pages are cached so that they can be quickly referenced from memory, to save disk reading time. Since page 1 is cached, multiple copies would be a waste of cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No. It is already in the buffer,

we don't load it again. If a new page comes and the buffer size is full we then replace the 1st entry.

**Consider your example:**

```
1,3,4,1,2,1,4,3,4,2,1

X X X X
1 
1 3
1 3 4
1 3 4 2  //Here 1 is already in the buffer, skip it!
```

**My Example:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

X X X X
1 
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 
5 2 3 4 // 1 is replaced
5 6 3 4 // 2 is replaced
5 6 7 4 // 3 is replaced
5 6 7 8 // 4 is replaced
```

Comment: So at that step i keep the old buffer?

Comment: You keep the old buffer, instead replace the one which came in first.